# perl Getopt::Long output issue

Tags: perl, getopt-long

Testing the Getopt::Long perl and when executed with arguments to options print command output is 1 instead supplied argument.

Here is the code..Could not locate what is missing here.

```
#!c:\Perl\bin
use Getopt::Long;

(@ARGV) or die "$0 --file <file name> --cb <CBEntry>";

GetOptions( "file" => \$file,
            "cb" => \$cb) or die "$0 --file <file name> --cb <CBEntry> :$! \n";

#print @ARGV;
print $file;
print $cb;
```

Comment: See "Options with values" in the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-values).

Answer (score 3):

The following indicates a argument-less option:

```
"file" => \$file
```

To accept a string argument, use the following:

```
"file=s" => \$file
```

[Option Specifications](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt::Long#Summary_of_Option_Specifications)